# Commands don't work. They used to work but they don't any more

Tags: python, discord

I added the bot status and after that the
Commands don't work. Added a answerers answer but it still no work ( help works not but not hello ;-;)

```
import discord
from KeepAlive import keep_alive

client=discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online,activity=discord.Game('Hey There! Do €help to start!'))
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(discord.Client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
        return
  if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    
  if message.content.startswith('$help'):
    await message.channel.send('no help here!')

  await bot.process_commands(message)

   

keep_alive()
client.run('wont say token :)')
```

Comment: What are you talking about? You don't appear to have added the underscore like they showed in their answer.

Comment: You can try to enable [`intents.message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Intents.messages).

Comment: It works now yay. How do i make the question answered?

Comment: @TechGamerExpert just click the checkmark next to answer that solved your issue or helped you the most in solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=commands#commands) and not "commands" that you run with `on_message` then you have to add `await client.process_commands(message)` ([check this issue in documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)). If your `on_message` event is not working then it's probably only because of missing `_` in `on_message` event.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message): # your forgot "_"
    if message.author == client.user: # discord.Client won't work. Use client.user instead
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    if message.content.startswith('$help'):
        await message.channel.send('no help here!')

    await client.process_commands(message) # add this line at the end of your on_message event
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your message function, it has `async def onmessage(message):` but the correct one is:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
```

And I recommend defining the prefix and then separating it from the message so you don't have to keep typing `$` in every `if`, and save the elements written after the command for future functions:

```py
PREFIX = "$"
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content[1:].split(' ')
    command = msg[0]
    if command == "hello":
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```